# React map inside map cloning on re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am rendering a map:

```
{categories.map((category, index) => {
```

and inside this map I am rendering another:

```
{challenges.map((challenge, index) => {
```

and they all render correctly but for example once I delete a challenge and call the getChallenges() (gets the challenges from server) which is what I also call at the first render with useEffect() it renders the categories properly but the challenges map inside the categories map gets doubled so I have the old & new ones. Anyway to prevent this or any way I can render the categories map and then the challenges map appending them to their correct category? Thanks for your help in advance I hope I was clear!

Comment: It pretty much goes down to how you populate the challenges array. I would advise you to simply overwrite it, but the issue itself is weird and could be caused by other factors. If you can give me more context I can try to help.

Comment: yeah so when I call the getChallenges() it calls the setChallenges() with react useState() inputting the new challenges

Comment: like even if I were to empty the challenges the map does not empty it keeps its old self

Comment: Also if I seperate the maps it does not clone

Comment: you need to share more code to allow us to see the problem. Specifically anywhere where you are updating the `challenges` array state.

Comment: Did you set `key` prop correctly in children to render Categories and Challenges? It would be good if you provide more codes.

Comment: Yes the key is correctly set to the value (always unique), for more code I can send you a paste bin is that good? so I can send the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

Solved because I was passing in an object as the 'key' so it was just [Object, Object] which made it not unique. Fixed by switching to challenge._id